# C: Segmentation fault, why and how to fix

Tags: c, libxml2

I'm currently learning how to program and i'm pretty sure my code is filled with errors.
 I have a segmentation fault when executing this code and i don't know why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libxml/parser.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
        int ac; /**< The player armor class. */
        char *class; /**< The player class. */
        char *cname; /**< The player character name. */
        int cp; /**< The player money (copper pieces, 100 CP = 1 GP). */
        int gp; /**< The player money (gold pieces). */
        int hp; /**< The player hit points. */
        char *name; /**< The player name. */
        int sp; /**< The player money (silver pieces, 10 SP = 1 GP). */
} player_t;

void parsePlayer(xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr node){
    int i = 1;
    player_t players[3];
    xmlNodePtr cur;

    node = node->xmlChildrenNode;

    while(node!=NULL){
        if (!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "player"))
        {
            players[i].name = (char *) xmlGetProp(node, (const xmlChar *)"name");
            printf("player %d name: %s\n", i, players[i].name);
            cur = node->xmlChildrenNode;
            players[i].ac = strtol((char *) xmlNodeListGetString(doc, cur->xmlChildrenNode, 1),NULL,10);
            i++;
        }

        node = node->next;
    }
}

void parsePlayers(xmlDocPtr doc){
    xmlNodePtr node;

    node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

    node = node->xmlChildrenNode; 

    while(node!=NULL){
        if (!xmlStrcmp(node->name, (const xmlChar *) "players")){
            parsePlayer(doc, node);
        }
        node = node->next;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {

    xmlDocPtr doc = xmlParseFile(argv[1]);

    if (doc != NULL) printf("DEBUG: File parsed.\n");   
    else { 
        fprintf(stderr,"Unable to parse the document \n");
        return 1;
    }

    parsePlayers(doc);
    return 0;
}
```

The code display this :

```
DEBUG: File parsed.
player 1 name: Camille /* correct */
Segmentation Fault
```

I've tried looking for answers but it seems i'm not advanced enough to understand them :/.
This is for a project in school (i have to fill several player_t structures).
I don't think the error comes from the XML so no need to post it here.
I've been stuck on this error for a few days now and i'd love to understand how to correct it.
Thanks for reading :).

EDIT: Thanks for your answer, gdb says :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10, group=<optimized out>, 
    loc=0x7ffff7a0f560 <_nl_global_locale>) at ../stdlib/strtol_l.c:292
292 ../stdlib/strtol_l.c: no such file or directory.
```

I have no idea what this means :(.

EDIT 2: Ok, the error was indeed from the xml, here it is :

```
<ddg name="The frozen cave">
        <date>
                <day>01</day>
                <month>09</month>
                <year>2019</year>
        </date>
        <dmname>Pierre</dmname>
        <players>
                <player name="Camille">
                        <ac>5</ac>
                        <class>Thief</class>
                        <cname>Camigolas</cname>
                        <hp>4</hp>
                        <money>
                                <cp>10</cp>
                                <gp>10</gp>
                                <sp>10</sp>
                        </money>
                </player>
                <player name="Jean">
                        <ac>4</ac>
                        <class>Fighter</class>
                        <cname>Jeragorn</cname>
                        <hp>8</hp>
                        <money>
                                <cp>3</cp>
                                <gp>1</gp>
                                <sp>2</sp>
                        </money>
                </player>
                <player name="Paul">
                        <ac>5</ac>
                        <class>Cleric</class>
                        <cname>Paumli</cname>
                        <hp>6</hp>
                        <money>
                                <cp>9</cp>
                                <gp>5</gp>
                                <sp>9</sp>
                        </money>
                </player>
        </players>
</ddg>
```

I've tried several things and ended up discovering that the xmlChildrenNode of player is text. 
I guess i just need to loop until i find the element i want but does anyone knows why it returns text ? (i just printf cur->name to discover that). 
 
Thank you all for you answers :)!

Comment: Compile your code with debug info (`-g`) and run it under gdb: `gdb --args ./myprog`.

Comment: Check what xmlNodeListGetString gives before calling strtol, as at least once you get a null pointer instead of a string (missing in the xml, or not where looked for, I guess)

Comment: I noticed that you're setting `cur = node->xmlChildrenNode`, but then using `cur->xmlChildrenNode` again in the call to `xmlNodeListGetString`.  Did you mean to do that?

Comment: It would be nice to include into post an example of xml file as well.

Comment: @schtever yes i wanted to do that so i go 2 down 2 levels and use "xmlNodeListGetString" to return the xmlChar * "5".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nptr=0x0` probably means that `strtol` (or more presisely the function that was called by `strtol`) was called with the parameter `nptr` set to `0x0`. The parameters `nptr` was most like expected to point to a valid string, but didn't.

What that likely means, is that `xmlNodeListGetString()` returns zero or `NULL`, depending on how you prefer to call the value.

When parsing external files, you should **ALWAYS** do error checking of the file content.

I would guess that `cur->xmlChildrenNode` doesn't have the value you expect it to, but it is hard to say without more info.

And by the way, `c` is one of those languages that has zero based arrays, so you should have `int i = 0`. (One based arrays are *evil*.) Do not be a heretic by simulating one-based arrays by having a dummy-element at `players[0]`.

Comment: so in my code players[0] exists ? ouch that's indeed pretty ugly then :(

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried several things and ended up discovering that the xmlChildrenNode of player is text.  I guess i just need to loop until i find the element i want but does anyone knows why it returns text

All whitespace between elements in XML files is significant.  The <Player> node will have 11 node children:

- a text node, the linebreak immediately after <Player> and spaces before <ac>
- an element node, which is <ac> (which will have a text node child, the ac value)
- a text node, the linebreak after </ac> and spaces before <class>
- an element node, which is <class>
- etc....

So that first "text" child you're seeing under <Player> is the newline and spaces that occur before <ac>.

You may want to pass XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS into xmlParseFile, which tells the parser to skip over "in-between" whitespace like this.  Then <Player> will have the <ac> child, then the <class> child, etc. without the text nodes between.